# Why does the Arquillian JaCoCo extension results in Method code too large?

Tags: maven, glassfish, jacoco, jboss-arquillian

in my Java EE 7 project I'm testing using Arquillian 1.1.11.Final and a managed Glassfish container. Since I want to check the code coverage, I want to integrate JaCoCo. I try use the Arquillian JaCoCo extension and configured it as follows:

```
...
<properties>
    <version.jacoco>0.7.9</version.jacoco>
    <version.arquillian_jacoco>1.0.0.Alpha9</version.arquillian_jacoco>
</properties>
...   
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.extension</groupId>
    <artifactId>arquillian-jacoco</artifactId>
    <version>${version.arquillian_jacoco}</version>
</dependency>
...
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
    <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${version.jacoco}</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <includes>*com/my/package/MyClassTest.java</includes>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
...
```

Running `mvn test` results in an error (Method code too large!).

```
...
[INFO] --- jacoco-maven-plugin:0.7.9:prepare-agent (default) @ test ---
[INFO] argLine set to -javaagent:C:\\Users\\stewe\\.m2\\repository\\org\\jacoco\\org.jacoco.agent\\0.7.9\\org.jacoco.agent-0.7.9-runtime.jar=destfile=C:\\Development\\projects\\project\\test\\target\\jacoco.exec,includes=*com/my/package/MyClassTest.java
...
Starting container using command: [java, -jar, c:\Development\payara41\glassfish\modules\admin-cli.jar, start-domain, --verbose, --debug, -t]
Aug 30, 2017 11:18:38 AM com.sun.enterprise.admin.launcher.GFLauncherLogger info
INFORMATION: JVM invocation command line:
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\bin\java.exe
// does not list the JaCoCo agent
...
Aug 30, 2017 11:18:59 AM org.jboss.arquillian.container.glassfish.clientutils.GlassFishClientUtil getResponseMap
SCHWERWIEGEND:  [status: SERVER_ERROR reason: Internal Server Error]
[ERROR] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 43.124 s <<< FAILURE! - in com.itac.smartdata.client.jobmanager.JobLoggingTest
[ERROR] com.itac.smartdata.client.jobmanager.JobLoggingTest  Time elapsed: 43.108 s  <<< ERROR!
javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: Failed to write asset to output: /lib/drools-compiler.jar
Caused by: org.jboss.shrinkwrap.api.exporter.ArchiveExportException: Failed to write asset to output: /lib/drools-compiler.jar
Caused by: org.jboss.shrinkwrap.api.exporter.ArchiveExportException: Failed to write asset to output: /org/drools/compiler/lang/DRL5Lexer.class
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not instrument Asset ByteArrayAsset [content size=114584bytes]
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Error while instrumenting class arquillian.
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Method code too large!
....
```

However, it works without the Arquillian JaCoCo extension and attaching the JaCoCo agent directly to the managed Glassfish in the domain.xml:

```
<jvm-options>-javaagent:C:\Development\jacocoagent.jar=destfile=C:\Development\test-coverage.exec,append=true,includes=com.my.package.*</jvm-options>
```

Question: Am I missing some configurations? The class that I include contains only short methods and works with the direct attachment. Why does the Arquillian extension fails?

Comment: Is it the same issue with Core 1.1.13.Final? There were changes for JDK8 introduced in this patch, so might be something related.

Comment: The problem was the include configuration. Removing it from pom.xml and adding `<extension qualifier="jacoco"><property name="includes">com.my.package.*</property></extension>` to arquillian.xml solved the problem. However, in contrast to directly attaching the agent to Glassfish, with the Arquillian Jacoco extension I get only the code coverage from the client JVM, but not the server-only classes.

Comment: Thank you for the hint with the version update. I changed that, but the problems remain the same.

Comment: Can you open an issue https://github.com/arquillian/arquillian-extension-jacoco/issues and ideally provide a reproducer project?